# How to execute PUT in curl in elastic search through python api

Tags: python, elasticsearch, curl

Below are two curl command.

I need to add the below content in curl in index of elasticsearch through python api, How to achieve this

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_country_index_5/country/1' -d '
{
 "name": "Afginastan"
}'


curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_country_index_5/state/1?parent=3' -d '
{
 "name": "Andra Pradesh",
 "country": "India"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_country_index_5/city/1?parent=5' -d '
{
 "name": "Kolhapur",
 "state": "Maharashtra"
}'
```

I have created index in python below is the code

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='my_country_index_5', ignore=400)
```

How to put in to same index(`my_country_index_5`) but different document `country, state, city`

```
doc = {
       "name": "Afginastan"
          }
res = es.index(index="my_country_index_5", id=1, body=doc)
print(res['result'])
```

Comment: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: @Ahmad, first curl is in `my_country_index_5/country`, second one is in `my_country_index_5/state`, and third one is in my_country_index_5/city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to have `type` which is shown in python as `doc_type`. `type` is omitted from version 7. In elasticsearch version lower than 7, you can have this by sending `doc_type` in the index arguments.

```
res = es.index(index="my_country_index_5", id=1, doc_type="state",  body=doc)
res = es.index(index="my_country_index_5", id=1, doc_type="city",  body=doc)
res = es.index(index="my_country_index_5", id=1, doc_type="country",  body=doc)
```